# What is the area of the region of the plane $x+y+z = 4$ lying within the cylinder $x^2+y^2 = 1$?

Tags: calculus

What is the area of the region of the plane $x+y+z = 4$ lying within the cylinder $x^2+y^2 = 1$? What is the standard way of calculating such thing? Is it an ellipse?

Comment: The intersection is not a surface, but a curve. Do you perhaps mean the region of the plane $x+y+z=4$ bounded by the intersection?

Comment: Yes, sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $3D$, $x^2+y^2=1$ is a cylinder. The plane $x+y+z=4$ intersects with the cylinder at an ellipse. Let the angle between the normal vector $(1,1,1)$ of the plane $x+y+z=4$ and the axial $z$-direction of the cylinder be $\theta$. Then we have $\cos\theta=1/\sqrt{3}$. Therefore the semimajor axis of the ellipse is $1/\cos\theta=\sqrt{3}$ and the semiminor axis is $1$. The area is $\pi\times\sqrt{3}\times 1=\sqrt{3}\pi$.

Comment: Can you be more detailed about how to calculate the semimajor axis?

Comment: The angle $\theta$ between the normal vector of $x+y+z=4$ and the axial direction of the cylinder is also the angle between the elliptical cross section and a circular cross section at right angle. So the semimajor axis times $\cos\theta$ should equal the radius of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$.

Answer (score 1):

With $z=4-x-y$ then apply the formula
$$
A=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}dydx = \int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{3}dydx=\color{blue}{\pi\sqrt{3}}
$$

Comment: Where can I find the formula?

Comment: Calculus books!

Comment: Can you tell me the name of the formula so I can search for it?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area#General_formula_for_surface_area